# What is the difference between cuboidal and columnar epithelium (other than their shape)?

Tags: tissue

The difference between squamous and cuboidal/columnar epithelium is clear. Squamous is used for filtration and diffusion while cuboidal/columnar is used for absorption and secretion.

But if both of them are used for absorption and secretion, what is the difference? Why would there be two different tissues that have the same function?

Comment: I hope this helps..https://pediaa.com/what-is-the-difference-between-cuboidal-and-columnar-cells/. If you still face any issues, let me know I'll give a detailed answer.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. The Biology.SE community has agreed that **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site as are ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) questions **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Under researched questions may be subject to down-voting and closure. Please consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details.